# Google map addListener for click is not working

Tags: google-maps

I am using the following code to draw a circle and get a click event, if I use it in a simple app inside the TwinCAT framework, it works fine.
But if I use it inside my real application then I don't get the click notification. In both cases, if I bring the mouse on the circle then the hand icons are different, same code gives different results, what could be the reasons? It looks like it is not z-order. Any other tips? When I get the first picture then it works OK. Thanks for the help.

[image]
[image]

```
<div id="mapdiv3" style="width:100%;height:100%" data-tchmi-zindex="0"></div>
<script>
   setTimeout(() => {
       initMap3();
   }, 1000)
       
   var circles3;       
   function initMap3() {
       var mapProp = {
           center: { lat: 63.320443, lng: 9.856220 },
           zoom: 16,
           minZoom: 1,
           fullscreenControl: false,
           zoomControl: false,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
       };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv3"), mapProp);
       circles3 = new Array();
   
       for (var city in citymap) {
           var populationOptions = {
               strokeColor: '#FF0000',
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 2,
               fillColor: '#FF0000',
               fillOpacity: 0.35,
               map: map,
               center: citymap[city].center,
               radius: Math.sqrt(.02) * 100
           };
           // Add the circle for this city to the map.
           var circle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
           circle.setMap(map);
           circles3.push(circle);
   
           google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function (e) {
               var locs = { lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng() };
   
               for (var ii = 0; ii < circles3.length; ii++) {
                   var b = circles3[ii].contains(new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng()));
                   if (b == true) {
                       console.log(Object.values(citymap)[ii].name);
                       break;
                   }
               }
           });
       }
       google.maps.Circle.prototype.contains = function (latLng) {
           return this.getBounds().contains(latLng) && google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.getCenter(), latLng) <= this.getRadius();
       }
   }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=geometry" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem, In TwinCAT framework we have a few modes and I was using ScaleToFill mode, which causes this problem. After changing it to none, all are fine. Unfortunately, some people think, this is the wrong question. [image]